# Package conflict while installing ms-sql in ubuntu. Broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, software-sources, mssql

I am trying to install ms sql in Ubuntu 20.04. Even I have got it installed in 20.04 successfully following [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15) guide but I sometime I have this problem multiple time and not sure why is this happening.

When I try to run following commads

`curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list`

`sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev`

I end up having below errors:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
>
> unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
>
> Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be inst
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

`sudo apt-cache policy <package>` shows multiple versions available for these packages. 
I tried installing the right versions for dependencies that did not help when I ran `sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev` again.

When I checked `msprod.list` file, it looks like 'https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod' the tailed `.list` is missing so I added that(not sure I should do that or not). Then I have got everything installed.

Now when I do `sudo apt update` it ends up with below error:

> E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
>
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
>
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I really don't understand what is happening and what I have to do to get thing working in simplest way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should drop the `.list` from your `sources.list` line. The without `list`, it points to a directory (that `apt` expect). With `.list`, it is a file with a `sources.list` line.
2. Note that every change you do to that file (including its initial addition), only gets effective when you run `apt update`.

The easiest way should be just use the file `msprod.list` as downloaded, although I'm not sure what exactly was your initial problem. I usually solve those using `aptitude`, which has a nice interactive solver.

Oh: and `unixodbc (= 2.3.7)` is sadly not yet in debian (or Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Switching the package version from 18.04 to 19.04 solved my issue on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
#Ubuntu 19.10
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
```

Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17